# How to deploy Google App Engine managed VMs using maven

Tags: google-app-engine

I've configured and deployed on the command line a managed vm using google cloud sdk.

How can managed VMs be deployed using jenkins and maven?

Comment: Is something missing from the article at https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/managed-vms/maven ?

Comment: Using that setup, will have to install manually the sdk on the jenkins slaves. It would be better to have only dependency on maven.

Comment: What about the push-to-deploy approach shown at https://cloud.google.com/tools/repo/push-to-deploy ?  That one does use jenkins (as well as Maven 3.1.0 or Gradle).

Comment: That solution only be fine if we only used jenkins inside google infrastructure. We allready have 3 instances of jenkins running inhouse, that for the time being, we have to maintain. With that solution it wouldn't be possible to build the project in inhouse jenkins.